# How to solve $2^x = 36$

Tags: logarithms

I need to solve $\log$ of $36$ in base $2$
The logarithm result $= x$.

$$
\log_ 2 36 = x.
$$
How do I determine value of $x$ in

$$
2^x=36
$$

I don't know how do it, since there's perfect square of this number.

Comment: You need to "solve" $\log_2 (36) = x$

Comment: Or $26$ or whatever.

Comment: edited. Thanks. I'm a bit tired.. sorry for the mistakes

Comment: After reading this comment, you will have surely heard of the "change of base" formula for logarithms. You should use that if you would like to compute a decimal approximation using a hand calculator.

Comment: If the fact that it isn't an integer is tough for you, you can think of it as solving $2^n = 36^m$, then $x = n/m$. But if you are using an electronic calculator, then just find $log(36)/log(2) = log_2(36)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a calculator, you can simply calculate:
$$x= \log_2 36 = \log 36 / \log 2$$
Without a calculator, you know that $x$ must be a little over $5$, since $2^5=32$. Now:
$$2^x = 2^{x-5}2^5 = 36 \to 2^{x-5}=36/32=1+1/8$$
Using the fact that for small $x$ $\log_b (1+x)\approx x/ \ln b$:
$$(x-5)=\log_2(1+1/8)\approx \frac{1}{8\ln 2}$$
$$x\approx 5+\frac{1}{8\ln 2}\approx5+\frac{1}{5.6}$$

Comment: Very very thanks! I'm doing to do without a calculator

Comment: I'm going to solve `log 5`, shouldn't it be something like `10^x = 5`? why do others solve it as `x=10^5`? it give very different result from my book and my calculator.